# loadChildren result in cannot find module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to convert an `Angular 2` Project into [Angular-cli Project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli)

In **app.routing.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [...
    {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: 'app/components/login/login.module#LoginModule'
    }...
]
```

All other routes are protected by `AuthGuard`

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }
    this.authService.redirectUrl = state.url;

    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```

When starting I'm getting the *much descriptive* error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'app/components/login/login.module'.
at webpackEmptyContext (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:43074:8)
at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:51438:40)
at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:51430:60)
at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:67227:128)
at RouterConfigLoader.load (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:67218:81)
at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:73950:111)
at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:66040:27)
at MergeMapSubscriber._next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:66030:18)
at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:42112:18)
at ScalarObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:69099:24)
```

I couldn't find any mention that loadingChildren using `Angular-cli` works different. 
What am i missing

***** EDIT **********

**login.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {LoginComponent} from "./login.component";
import {loginRouting} from "../../routes/login.routing";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        loginRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        LoginComponent
    ]
 })

export class LoginModule {}
```

Relative Path: src/app/components/login/login.module.ts

Comment: mos probably your path is not correct, either login.module file is incorrect. please post login.module code too

Comment: @PardeepJain Thanks for the quick response. added login.module

Comment: seems your login.module file correct. is there any local access to your code somewhere like github etc so that i can see whole code ?

Comment: Sadly No. I can't give access to this code currently. Thanks however

Comment: hmm not an issue :)

Comment: only for me /-:

Comment: So did you find the answer? Having the same problem here.